# Zend link Button

Tags: html, zend-framework

How can one create a link to a particular action, tried this method below but its not working properly, bare in mind I also have a folder countaing the controller, admim/controller/action

```
<button type="button"><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' =>'smme', 'action' => 'client'))?>">Previous</a></button>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can do something like that:

```
$button = new Zend_Form_Element_button('button');
$button->setAttrib('id', 'bouton');
$button->setLabel('Previous');
$button->setAttrib('onClick', "parent.location='" . Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl() .'/smme/client' ."'");
```

Comment: Works perfectly thanks.  By the way doydoy are you a zend developer?

Comment: You're welcome. :) I not a developper of Zend, but I develop with Zend. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the compliment, it makes me happy :) If only it was always the case. ;)